# What is the pronunciation of "species"

Tags: pronunciation, plural-forms

What is the pronunciation of "*species*"? I know they have the same form whether it be in the singular or the plural form.

Both in the singular and plural forms, it is pronounced the same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are.  However, I should also point out that there are two alternative pronunciations of the word: SPEE-seez and SPEE-sheez.

Comment: I think the former might be specific to American English.  (I'm not really sure, but I noticed MacMillan only lists it as an alternative in their AmE dictionary, not their BrE dictionary.)